# Correct way to check if local variable equals local variable

Tags: php, function, mysqli, syntax, local-variables

This does not evaluate, even when the values should be equal, and it goes straight to the else event. The table column names match the database, so...

Do I need some type of quotes in ($recruitcheck==$recruitpass)?

```
$recruiter = $_POST["recruiter"];
$recruitpass = $_POST["recruitpass"];
$recruitcheck = mysqli_query($maindb, "select aurapass from auras where auraname='$recruiter'");
if($recruitcheck == $recruitpass) {
    $badgecheck = mysqli_query($maindb, "select recruitbadge from auras where auraname='$recruiter'");
    if($badgecheck == "0") {
        echo "<script>alert('Recruiter information correct, but there is no recruit badge.')</script>";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Recruiter badge accepted.')</script>";
        $emailcheck = mysqli_query($maindb, "select * from auras where email='$email'");
        $namecheck = mysqli_query($maindb, "select * from auras where auraname='$auraname'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($emailcheck) > 0 || mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) > 0){
            echo "<script>alert('New auraname/email is already taken.')</script>";
            exit();
        } else {
            exit();                        
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Aura information of recruiter is incorrect. Please, use preexisting aura information to confirm recruiter identity.')</script>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: `$recruitpass` is a string, `$recruitcheck` is __not__ a string.

Comment: Check you variables by printing them out with `var_dump`. `mysqli_query` returns a resource so it will never be equal to a string value. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Fetch rows to get data from db.

Comment: For the love of god, don't store passwords as plain text. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$recruitpass is a string, whereas $recruitcheck is **mysqli_result** object. You need to fetch the string value **inside** the object before comparing it to $recruitpass

Comment: After some intense digging, I found mysqli_fetch_assoc worked to store the mysqli_query results as strings. Since it is store in an associative manner, the strings can be called by $variable['columnname']. To compare, check $variable['columnname']==$stringvariable. In my case, $recruitfetch=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recruitcheck); if($recruitfetch['aurapass']==$recruitpass{ code works }. Thank you all!